# Testing destroy with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this in controllers

```
   def destroy
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
        @post.destroy
    end
```

But I'm lost as to how to actually test if it works. Any pointers would be highly appreciated! I currently have this in my RSpec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'


RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  it "must have a title" do
    post= Post.create
    expect(post.errors[:title]).to_not be_empty
  end 
  it "must have a description" do
    post= Post.create
    expect(post.errors[:description]).to_not be_empty
  end 
  it "must have a location" do
    post= Post.create
    expect(post.errors[:location]).to_not be_empty
  end 
  it "must have an image" do
    post= Post.create
    expect(post.errors[:image]).to_not be_empty
  end 
  it "can be destroyed" do
    post= Post.destroy

  end 
end
```

Comment: You'll want some Controller tests (hint: `rspec.describe PostsController, type: :controller`), where you can test controller endpoints. Take a look at the docs: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/controller-specs/controller-spec

Comment: What do you mean by "test if it works"? you don't need to test that some objects gets destroyed when you call `destroy` on it, activerecords takes care of testing that. You can be confident that calling `destroy` on an object just works. What you may have is some before_destroy callback and you may want to test that, but your current example does not need to be tested. Also, you are showing controller code but model tests.

Comment: @HenryKeiter The prevailing advice these days is to write [request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/request-specs/request-spec), not controller specs. (The main reason controller specs aren't officially deprecated is that there are so many already written in old code bases!). Request specs are basically the same thing, except that you're testing the *full* rails stack; including the router.

Comment: @TomLord Fair enough!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the count of thing has change by -1, like this:

```
expect { delete '/things', :thing => { :id => 123'} }.to change(Thing, :count).by(-1)
```

This means that you want to have one less 'thing' and and is ensuring that something has been deleted.

If you want to ensure that specific "thing" was deleted, you can create one before the test, pass the "thing" id as param, and ensure that this doesn't exists on database, like this:

```
thing = create(:thing)
delete '/things', :thing => { :id => thing.id'}

expect(Thing.find_by(id: thing.id)).to be_nil
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, if you use request specs ( see https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-9/docs/request-specs/request-spec ) you can easily call the API that should delete the model, and then do an ActiveRecord query to expect no results.

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "delete thing api" do

  it "deletes thing" do

    // Create a thing with a factory of your choice here

    delete "/things", :thing => {:id => 1}

    expect(Thing.all.count).to be 0
  end
end
```